# Join that returns all left table records when the right table is connected through a linking table

Tags: sql, oracle11g, toad

I am having some trouble trying to figure out how to write a SQL statement that will return the same amount of records found in the left table. The only way to get data from the right table is to use a 3rd table.

For instance, I have three tables, Sites, Addresses, and Affiliations. Many affiliations can be active for a site (Contact, Mailing Address, Owner, and Official), but there may not be a person or address associated with the affiliation. IE. A site may have a Contact person but no Official designated, or a site may not yet have a Mailing Address assigned.
The Sites (left table) and Affiliations are linked by a common ID.
Sites.ID = Affiliations.Site_ID

The Affiliations and Addresses (right table) are linked by a common Address Record ID
Affiliations.Address_RID = Addresses.RID

The query I have is

```
SELECT A.ID,
    A.NAME,
    C.ADDR_1,
    C.CITY_NAME,
    C.STATE_CODE,
    C.POSTAL_CODE
FROM SITES A,
    AFFILIATIONS B,
    ADDRESSES C
WHERE A.ID = B.SITE_ID
    AND B.ADDRESS_RID = C.RID
    AND B.AFFILIATION_TYPE = 'MAILING ADDRESS'
ORDER BY A.ID
```

The results I get if I query the sites table alone is 1580 site records. Running the above query for mailing addresses I get 1386 records.  I need to return all 1580 records with nulls for records where mailing addresses are absent.
I'm doing something wrong, but I am not seeing it.

Comments?

Thanks

Comment: It may make more sense to break your logic down into 2 or 3 separate queries, use a temp table to join them and when you can clearly see your logic in SQL you can combine all your subqueries. By the way, you've currently joined the tables, it isn't exactly clear what you're joining on. Use the join keyword and don't join in a where clause

Comment: I wondered if using subqueries would be the route to go. There are actually 3 more tables which I use for filters than I put in the example.  The queries would be 1 for sites which meet conditions in 2 joined tables (1580 records). 1 for contact information based on the sites resulting in 1521 contacts. And 1 for mailing addresses returning 1386 records.

Answer (score 0):

You should try left join and if it will not work then remove where condition.

```
SELECT A.ID,
    A.NAME,
    C.ADDR_1,
    C.CITY_NAME,
    C.STATE_CODE,
    C.POSTAL_CODE
FROM SITES A,
left join AFFILIATIONS B  on A.ID = B.SITE_ID
left join ADDRESSES C on B.ADDRESS_RID = C.RID
    WHERE 
     B.AFFILIATION_TYPE = 'MAILING ADDRESS'
ORDER BY A.ID
```

Comment: Your left join to Affiliations B is pointless because you then apply a predicate on B in the where clause.

Answer (score 0):

The "old" Oracle syntax for outer joins is like this:-

```
SELECT A.ID,
    A.NAME,
    C.ADDR_1,
    C.CITY_NAME,
    C.STATE_CODE,
    C.POSTAL_CODE
FROM SITES A,
    AFFILIATIONS B,
    ADDRESSES C
WHERE A.ID = B.SITE_ID (+)
    AND B.ADDRESS_RID = C.RID (+)
    AND B.AFFILIATION_TYPE (+) = 'MAILING ADDRESS'
ORDER BY A.ID
```

But you really should be using the ANSI syntax - it is much easier to see what is a join condition and what is a filter:-

```
SELECT A.ID,
    A.NAME,
    C.ADDR_1,
    C.CITY_NAME,
    C.STATE_CODE,
    C.POSTAL_CODE
FROM SITES A
LEFT JOIN AFFILIATIONS B ON A.ID = B.SITE_ID AND B.AFFILIATION_TYPE = 'MAILING ADDRESS'
LEFT JOIN ADDRESSES C ON B.ADDRESS_RID = C.RID
ORDER BY A.ID
```

Note that the condition on the Affiliation type needs to go in the join clause. if you include it in the where clause then you won't return any rows that don't have a 'MAILING ADDRESS' affiliation type.

Comment: Thanks! I was still using the "old" Oracle syntax since that was what I had learned, and we haven't upgraded in quite some time (state lack of funding, of course) so I wasn't using the ANSI syntax. It is much easier to see what I'm joining.